# Styling of text and links in store

Tags: bug, status-completed, usability, design, shop

On the [store front page](http://shop.stackexchange.com/), there are two prominent lines of text. The one that is underlined at the top is **not**  a link. The one at the bottom **is** a link. Should the text underlining be reversed?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed - thanks for pointing it out